# User has google account or email account logout force closed firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've logined google account on the application but when I logout of the system, the application force closed. In another, couldn't show google account chooser when I started to login the application again

This was the code I've tried and the problem is null object reference on methode GoogleSignIn Client and I couldn't find method revokeaccess cause it was unavailable.

Login Activity.java

```
package id.co.dolansemarang.loginfirebaseds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;

public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Login User";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1234;

    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Button btnLogin;
    LinearLayout btnGoogleSignIn;
    EditText edtEmailLogin, edtPasswordLogin;
    TextView tvResetPass;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuthLogin;
//    DatabaseReference userRefLogin;
    FirebaseUser curUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        btnLogin = findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        edtEmailLogin = findViewById(R.id.edt_email_login);
        edtPasswordLogin = findViewById(R.id.edt_password_login);
        tvResetPass = findViewById(R.id.tv_reset_pass);
        btnGoogleSignIn = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in_with_google);



        //Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();


        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(LoginActivity.this)
                .enableAutoManage(LoginActivity.this, this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

        firebaseAuthLogin = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvResetPass.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnGoogleSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);

        updateUI(curUser);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // cek apakah pengguna sudah pernah masuk sehingga ada update UI disini
        FirebaseUser currentUser = firebaseAuthLogin.getCurrentUser();
        updateUI(currentUser);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try{
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                loginWithGoogle(account);

            }
            catch (ApiException e){
                Log.w(TAG, "Google Sign I Failed", e);
                updateUI(curUser);
            }
        }
    }

    private void loginWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        Log.d(TAG, "FirebaseAuthWithGoogle" +account.getId());
        showProgressDialog();

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(),null);
        firebaseAuthLogin.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "your account has been success to register");
                            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuthLogin.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);

                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "please, try again", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Gagal Login, silakan coba lagi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    updateUI(null);
                        }
                        hideProgressDialog();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void loginUserWithFirebase(String email, String password) {
        Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
        if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }
        showProgressDialog();
        firebaseAuthLogin.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "your account has been success to register");
                    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuthLogin.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);

                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "please, try again", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Gagal Login, silakan coba lagi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                    updateUI(null);
                }
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        hideProgressDialog();
        if (user != null && user.isEmailVerified()) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(this, "Welcome " + user.getEmail() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        } else if (user != null && !user.isEmailVerified()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please verify your Email, first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Selamat datang");
        }
    }

    private boolean validateForm() {
        boolean valid = true;
        String email = edtEmailLogin.getText().toString();
        String password = edtPasswordLogin.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Harap isi email kembali", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            valid = false;
        } else {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Harap isi password kembali", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                valid = false;
            } else {
                if (password.length() <= 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "password contained minimum 6 character", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return valid;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if (i == R.id.btn_login) {
            loginUserWithFirebase(edtEmailLogin.getText().toString(), edtPasswordLogin.getText().toString());
        } else if (i == R.id.tv_reset_pass) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else if(i == R.id.btn_sign_in_with_google){
            signInGoogle();
        }

    }

    private void signInGoogle() {
        Intent signIntent = googleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

Main Activity.java

```
package id.co.dolansemarang.loginfirebaseds;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuthMain;
    FirebaseUser user;
    Button btnKeluar;
    GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient;
    GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnKeluar = findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        firebaseAuthMain = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        btnKeluar.setOnClickListener(this);
        user = firebaseAuthMain.getCurrentUser();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int i = v.getId();
        if(i == R.id.btn_sign_out){
//            firebaseAuthMain.signOut();
//            googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
//                @Override
//                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
//                    updateUI(null);
//                }
//            });
//            updateUI(user);
            signOutApp();
            signOutGoogle();
        }
    }

    private void signOutGoogle() {
        googleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener(this,
                new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        updateUI(null);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void signOutApp() {
            firebaseAuthMain.signOut();
            updateUI(user);
    }

    private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
        if(user != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(this,"Thanks for visiting",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected when I login with either email or google account and then Logout without conflict. So, How should I do?

Comment: Okay. I will edit my question later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the document here [google-signin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)

Just only `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` to logout

So you might have to call signOutApp() function only.

Comment: In addition, updateUI() was called twice. the MainActivity does not exist for the second call that causes a null pointer

Comment: So that,  should I remove googlesigninclient.sign out? How I can login with different account?

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Finally, I find my solution. I changed the code    ``` googleSignInClient.signOut()```  became ```Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient)```